# ListFolderAsync funcion returns null in Dropbox.NET SDK C#

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use Dropbox.Net SKD to get my dropbox name and all files and folders in the root path.

```
     var listIt = Task.Run((Func<Task>)ListRoot);
     listIt.Wait();


     async Task ListRoot()
    {
        using (var connect = new DropboxClient("ACCESSTOKEN"))
        {
            var get = await connect.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(get.Name.DisplayName);

            var list = await connect.Files.ListFolderAsync("");

            foreach (var item in list.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i just get my Dropbox name.

While list = null.

How can I get the folder items?

Comment: This code can't possibly compile. Could you share your actual code?

Comment: And what's the exact exception you get? (Please include the stack trace.)

Comment: Solved it, it was about the permissons of the Dropbox app

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What permissions did you provide?